# Retrieve Java Object from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I managed to get the object with this code:

```
public void retrieveUser(final String email){
        firebaseUsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(messageSnapshot.getKey().equals(Email.encodeID(email))){

                        retrievedUser = messageSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

(Please note `retrievedUser` is a class attribute, thus a field.)

I am accessing that field from the code, but even I see it takes the value on the debugger, it is being null on the calling code.

Any hint? Can´t I just return it in the method itself, so it would be?:

```
public User retrieveUser(final String email);
```

So, to sum up, how can I return the `User` object itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Firebase loads and synchronizes data **asynchronously**. You can't be sure that your field `retrievedUser` will have a value when you access it because you don't know when Firebase will call the `onDataChange` event.

You have to do your work that depends on `retrievedUser` in the `onDataChange` event handler like this.

```
firebaseUsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if(messageSnapshot.getKey().equals(Email.encodeID(email))){
                retrievedUser = messageSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                doSomethingWithTheUser(retrievedUser);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer buddy, I will mark it as the correct one, but before I´ve got a few questions; so basically this means I am forced to implement the logic on the onDataChange section right pal?

Comment: Yes, but you can call a method like i did in the answer so your code is still well organized. This asynchronous nature of Firebase is very useful because it will not block your thread, you can keep on doing other work and handle the response from Firebase when it arrives.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to return the retrievedUser object using a callback or a return statment. Below is some code that shows how to return the value using a callback.

```
    @Override
public void getEvents(final LoadEventsCallback callback) {

    final List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://austin-feeds-me.firebaseio.com/events");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Event event = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                events.add(event);
            }
            callback.onEventsLoaded(events);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: What is LoadEventsCallback? It does not belong to Firebase, and I am not sure if I have to implement it

Comment: It is a callback that I defined and is not specific to Firebase. It is from a project I'm working on you can see here: https://github.com/Austin-Droids/austin-feeds-me/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/utfeedsme/data/EventsDataSource.java